# Which control to use to make a Google Play style horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview, android-controls

I am trying to make a horizontal scrolling list much like one we can find in the Google Play app. I have made the fragment (100dp x 150dp), and the adapter, but am struggling to find an element that will work.

**The fragment looks like this :**

[image]

It is just a cardview with a imageview, and a couple textviews within.

**My goal is to make many of them together, horizontally, and scrollable like this:**

[image]

I tried using a ViewPager, but that only allows for one full screen element, but I need a list that continues off the page. A HorizontalScrollView on the other hand would not "snap" to an element as seen in the gif above.

Any suggestions on which element would suite this the best?

Comment: did you try two way grid view or horizontal grid inside a vertical listview

Comment: use horizontal scroll view

Comment: `RecyclerView` + `LinearLayoutManager`..

Comment: @Mohit the horizontal scroll view does not snap each element to the left side of the screen,  but keeps it where you stopped scrolling.

Comment: @santoXme ok I will try that.  Do you know if we can make the elements snap to the edge of the screen?

Comment: @jayS. pardon but i m not understand what u want to say...

Comment: @santoXme take a look at the gif. I'm not scrolling completely,  only part way,  and the control is snapping so the the closest element ends up on the left. When I try to scroll past the app 'Township'  I didn't scroll enough,  so it snapped back.

Comment: you want that same this for your application .snap the item to edge of that device ...form both side or or single side?

Comment: @santoXme both sides.  If I scroll more than half,  snap to the next element,  else snap back to the current element

Comment: you can get this by creating a custom horizontal scroll-view ..using gesture detractor ..and if your all item size  horizontal scroll view  is same than is very easy to get a snap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98645/discussion-between-santoxme-and-jay-s).

Comment: A viewpager can be implemented to show multiple views at once too. Look at this [link](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)

Comment: @Amy I used your solution, and it worked great for me. If you would like to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `RecyclerView` "pattern" and simply use a `LinearLayoutManager` with its `orientation` set to `HORIZONTAL`.

Comment: but how to repeat it dynamically as shown in above image, Different horizontal views for different categories. Please update. I want to make it dynamic .

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use ViewPage and implement an PagerAdapter. In the custom PagerAdapter, override method `getPageWidth()`, adjust page width as the card's width.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with Horizontal RecyclerView, make Horizontal LinearLayoutManager like below code

```
RecyclerView rclViewOrder;
rclViewOrder.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

rclViewOrder.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new ViewOrderWaiterAdapter(activity, orderItemInfoList);
rclViewOrder.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```